# angular6 reactive forms chrome autocomplete not setting value in the input box

Tags: forms, angular6, reactive

We are using Angular with reactive forms.
On an input box for address if u start typing ex: '7' and select a value from the autocomplete drop down, the selected value is not set and it goes back to the value I typed like '7'.

```
  <div class="col-12 profile-info-form__input-section">
    <label class="form-label--above">
      <span i18n>Address</span>
    </label>
    <input type="text" class="profile-info-form__input" formControlName="address" />
    <span i18n class="form-error" [ngClass]="(profileForm.get('address').errors && profileForm.get('address').errors.required && profileForm.get('address').touched) ? 'form-error--show' : ''">Enter your Address</span>
    <span i18n class="form-error" [ngClass]="(profileForm.get('address').errors && profileForm.get('address').errors.maxLength && profileForm.get('address').touched) ? 'form-error--show' : ''">Invalid</span>
  </div>
```

[image]

[image]

This doesn't happen if u pick a value on focus of the input field.
Any help on this issue is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

just ran into same thing today. for now i had to add autocomplete="nope" on all inputs to get around it ("off" didn't do it [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Securing_your_site/Turning_off_form_autocompletion#Disabling_autocompletion)). interestingly i tried in an older angular 5.2.5 app and didnt seem to have this problem..